# Can I use win32com client for macOS?

Tags: python, macos, win32com

I have been looking at Pycel and Xlrd libraries. The issue with using them on a Mac is that both libraries are using win32com.client to read in the Excel files.

So I want to know:

1. Is there a way I can use `win32com` client for macOS?
2. If not, can I use something similar to `win32com` library, but for macOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No.
2. Not quite. But instead of using COM to drive around Excel you can use the cross-platform UNO to drive around LibreOffice via either PyUNO or [unotools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unotools).